# Page Viewer with Side Menu (Navigation drawer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation-drawer, uipageviewcontroller

I am using [REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController) as a side menu controller, the problem is this menu will appear from any point of screen, I want it to be like the Android version, which will appear only if you start swiping from the start left of screen, if swiping from any other point, the menu will not appear.

I want this because I am having a Page viewer inside this menu.
Since I am new in IOS, I looked inside the library code and didn't find any function that define the starting point also tried to modify the message
panGestureRecognized it didn't work .

So I'd like to suggest me a help or any other library that have the option.

Comment: Try something like this. In this library : set NO the "panGestureEnabled" in this libray. and Implement your own gesture in your viewcontroller for left to right. When it get called open your sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have follow this Library then i think you have put this code too

```
In ViewDidLoad

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognized:)]];

And 

- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    // Dismiss keyboard (optional)
    //
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.frostedViewController.view endEditing:YES];

    // Present the view controller
    //
    [self.frostedViewController panGestureRecognized:sender];
}
```

Replace Above code with below code.

```
Confirm UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Delegate protocol

@interface DEMONavigationController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

In ViewDidLoad

    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftEdgeGesture:)];
    leftEdgeGesture.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
    leftEdgeGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftEdgeGesture];}

And
- (void)handleLeftEdgeGesture:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state ||
       UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gesture.state) {
        [self.frostedViewController presentMenuViewController];


    }else{
        // DO nothing
    }
}
```